# Double Integrals of Force

Tags: forces, energy, momentum, integration

I took AP Physics C and Multivariable Calculus last year, and noticed something interesting. For non-relativistic particles in one dimension:$$F=\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}$$
where  $E=-U$. Because of mixed partial equality, wouldn't this mean that $$p=\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x}$$ and $$E=\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t}=-U$$
where $\zeta$ is some function, so that $$F=\frac{\partial^2\zeta}{\partial t\,\partial x}=\frac{\partial^2\zeta}{\partial x\,\partial t}$$
So, I went about trying to find $\zeta$ for a field with no net force.
$$F=0$$
$$p=\int 0\,dt=p_0$$
$$E=\int 0\,dx=E_0$$
$$\zeta=\int p_0\,dx=p_0x+\zeta_0$$
$$\zeta=\int E_0\,dt=E_0t+\zeta_0$$
Equating these two $\zeta$ functions, I got
$$p_0x+\zeta_0=E_0t+\zeta_0$$
which is the same as
$$mv_0x=\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2t$$
$$x=\frac{1}{2}v_0t$$
This seems like it has to be wrong though, because no net force means that $x=v_0t$.
My question is, is there something I did wrong here?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: That could be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the acceleration is not a partial derivative! Its a *total* derivative, $\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dt}$, with a $\mathrm d$ instead of a $\partial$. Anyway, I guess you might want to read about the [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation).